# Tensorflow Divide Operation

Tags: python, tensorflow, divide

I'm trying to quantize an output of a convolution operation in Tensorflow. My convolution layer's output's shape is (1, 38, 38, 64). I have a vector (shape is (1,64)) to quantize each filter output. There are 64 filter an each filter should be quantized with a quantizer from the vector. I tried divide operation but the result is not correct. What can I do?

```
conv_op=convolve(img, filt)
q_standard = [[16, 11, 10, 16, 124, 140, 151, 161],
          [12, 12, 14, 19, 126, 158, 160, 155],
          [14, 13, 16, 24, 140, 157, 169, 156],
          [14, 17, 22, 29, 151, 187, 180, 162],
          [18, 22, 37, 56, 168, 109, 103, 177],
          [24, 35, 55, 64, 181, 104, 113, 192],
          [49, 64, 78, 87, 103, 121, 120, 101],
          [72, 92, 95, 98, 112, 100, 103, 199]]
weight_quantization = tf.get_variable('weight_quantization',initializer=tf.reshape(q_standard, [1, 64, -1, 1]))
quantized= tf.divide(conv_op,weight_quantization)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    initd=tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(initd)
    sess.run(quantized)
    print(quantized.eval())
```

Comment: If you're output shape is (1, 38, 38, 64) shouldn't tf.reshape use [1,1,-1,64]?

Comment: Convolution layer's output's shape is 1,38,38,64 and  I have 64 different quantizer for each 38x38 output of the convolution layer ouput.

Comment: So weight_quantization should be 1x1x1x64. You've got it as 1x64x1x1. IE axes don't match

Comment: I had already tried both but still, have the same problem.

Comment: Can you provide sample input and your expected output? Maybe for a toy example (1, 2, 2, 5)

Comment: I tried it with toy example and it is working correctly. I think I have another problem with my original data. Thanks @JeremyVoisey.